# Css / Styled Comp Animation background gradient

Tags: css, styled-components

Hello I'm having trouble making an animation in a gradient bacgrkound with the styled component I don't know where I am wrong:

code:

```
import React from "react";
import "./styles.css";
import styled, { css, keyframes } from "styled-components";

const HeaderKeyFrame = keyframes`
    0% {
        background-position: 0% 50%;
    }
    50% {
        background-position: 100% 50%;
    }
    100% {
        background-position: 0% 50%;
    }
`;
const Div = styled.div`
  height:100vh,
  position: relative;
  flex: none;
  height: 530px;
  background-position: top center;
  background: linear-gradient(-45deg, #ee7752, #e73c7e, #23a6d5, #23d5ab);
  animation: ${HeaderKeyFrame} 15s ease infinite;
  -webkit-clip-path: polygon(0 0, 100% 0, 100% calc(100% - 2vw), 0 100%);
  clip-path: polygon(0 0, 100% 0, 100% calc(100% - 2vw), 0 100%);
`;

export default function App() {
  return (
    <Div className="App">
      <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
      <h2>Start editing to see some magic happen!</h2>
    </Div>
  );
}
```

example: https://codesandbox.io/s/friendly-swanson-syuln

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To change the background position, you need the background's size to be greater than the container - `background-size: 200% 100%;` for example ([sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/jovial-babbage-67kkd?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark)).

```
const Div = styled.div`
  height: 100vh,
  position: relative;
  flex: none;
  height: 530px;
  background-position: top center;
  background: linear-gradient(-45deg, #ee7752, #e73c7e, #23a6d5, #23d5ab);
  animation: ${HeaderKeyFrame} 15s ease infinite;
  background-size: 200% 100%;
  clip-path: polygon(0 0, 100% 0, 100% calc(100% - 2vw), 0 100%);
`;
```